# JQuery - create NEW radio buttons

Tags: jquery

Ok here's what I have so far.. thanks to Paolo.
And it works fine, but only if I have existing radio button options.

What if I need to create a NEW radio button without any pre-existing ones?

Ultimately what I want to do is create an array of options, loop through them and output 
a list of options as radio buttons. So originally, there will be NO radio buttons within the 'abc' div.

Thanks in advance!

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
  // add a new input when a new color is chosen, for example
  $('#aaa').change(function() {
      var radio = $('<input>').attr({
          type: 'radio', name: 'colorinput', value: '2', id: 'test'
      });
      $(':radio:last-child', '#abc').after(radio).after('option 3 ');
  });
});

</script>

<form id='abcdef'>
  <select id="aaa">
    <option>red</option>
    <option>blue</option>
    <option>other</option>
  </select>

  <div id="abc">
    Input<BR>
    option 1 <input type="radio" name="colorinput" value="1" /> 
    option 2 <input type="radio" name="colorinput" value="2" /> 
  </div>
  <BR>
</form>
```

Comment: Hmm the script and html didn't format very well :(

Comment: indent it with four spaces or use the code button in the editor, and it'll be nice and neat... :)

Comment: Whoops. I didn't know your final intent was to have no radios to start off. Sorry for the unhelpful code in your previous question. :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ok given your updated question, this should do it (or be pretty darn close):

```
  $(function() {
    $("#aaa").change(function() {
      $('<input type="radio" name="colorInput" id="test" value="2">')
        .appendTo($("#abc")).before('Option 3');
    });
  });
```

Things to bear in mind:

- You can construct the HTML directly in the jQuery constructor;
- I assume you will be using dynamic IDs, values and labels. That's simply a question of concatenating strings and variables in the expression;
- You probably need to check for duplicates (not covered above);
- If you're putting them in a div like you seem to, after the approach above rather than what I originally suggested (ie $(":radio:last")) as its faster and clearer and doesn't rely on their being a radio button in existence already; and
- Newly constructed HTML elements won't have any relevant event handlers on them unless you're using the jQuery 1.3 live() event handler.

Comment: Ok so I tried that... doesn't seem to work

$(document).ready(function() {
    // add a new input when a new color is chosen, for example
    $('#aaa').change(function() {
  
       $('<input type="radio" name="blah">').after($(':radio:last','#abc'));
       
    });
});

Comment: This works! Thank you!  But for some reason it does display 'Option 3' at the end of the radio button - I do the the radio button though.

Comment: I assume you mean it doesn't because I tried it and you're quite right. Changed it to use before() for the text and that works and matches your existing options. You can obviously use after() instead to put the label after the radio button.

Answer (score 4):

Instead of dealing with the [after](http://docs.jquery.com/Manipulation/after#content) and trying using the [append](http://docs.jquery.com/Manipulation/append#content).  This way you don't have to check for the last radio button and the functionality will work when there are 0 radio buttons at startup.

```
var radio = $('<input>').attr({
      type: 'radio', name: 'colorinput', value: '2', id: 'test'
  });
$('#abc').append(radio.after('option 3'));
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$(":radio:last").after('<input type="radio" name="blah">');
```

Comment: $(":radio:last").after('<input type="radio" name="blah">');

.. works fine. But ONLY if I have a pre-existing radiobutton. Otherwise.. I get nothing.  I want to create new radio buttons within the div.. <div id="abc">Input<BR> *insert new jquery created radio buttons here </div>